# Is there a way to directly consume a Rayon chain without collecting it first?

Tags: rust, rayon

I am using Rayon to produce reasonably large return values. This uses a lot of memory when collecting all returned values into a `Vec`. Is there a way to avoid creating a `Vec` and directly consuming as an iterable?

Here is an example which doesn't work:

```
fn main() {
    let numbers: Vec<_> = "12.03 0.3 44.2 45 zzz".split_whitespace().collect();

    let x = numbers
        .par_iter()
        .map(|n| n.parse::<f32>())
        .filter_map(|n| n.ok());

    for n in x {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `rayon::iter::FilterMap<rayon::iter::Map<rayon::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, [closure@src/main.rs:10:14: 10:34]>, [closure@src/main.rs:11:21: 11:31]>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
   |
13 |     for n in x {
   |              ^ `rayon::iter::FilterMap<rayon::iter::Map<rayon::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, [closure@src/main.rs:10:14: 10:34]>, [closure@src/main.rs:11:21: 11:31]>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `rayon::iter::FilterMap<rayon::iter::Map<rayon::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, [closure@src/main.rs:10:14: 10:34]>, [closure@src/main.rs:11:21: 11:31]>`
   = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4e9415c711a6f55b684ad29832cba714&version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015)

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and don't just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`ParallelIterator::for_each`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.2/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.for_each):

```
extern crate rayon; // 1.0.2

use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let numbers = ["12.03", "0.3", "44.2", "45", "zzz"];

    let x = numbers.par_iter().flat_map(|n| n.parse::<f32>());

    x.for_each(|n| {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    });
}
```

Related:

- [`ParallelIterator::for_each_with`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.2/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.for_each_with)
- [`ParallelIterator::try_for_each`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.2/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.try_for_each)
- [`ParallelIterator::try_for_each_with`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.2/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.try_for_each_with)

See also:

- [How to satisfy the Iterator trait bound in order to use Rayon here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42721458/155423)